# MySQL: Does `DROP TABLE` completely remove the table or just the structure?

Tags: mysql

I am under the impression that the MySQL command `DROP TABLE User` will just remove the data, columns, and relevant constraints. However, the table shell still exists. Is this correct?

Comment: What is a table shell?

Comment: As per docs *Be careful with this statement! It removes the table definition and all table data. For a partitioned table, it permanently removes the table definition, all its partitions, and all data stored in those partitions. It also removes partition definitions associated with the dropped table* [13.1.29 DROP TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html)

Comment: Oh! So I guess it completely removes the table. In that case, I now presume that it should be possible to create a new table with the same name!? Doing `DROP TABLE user;` followed by `CREATE TABLE user ( ... );` should work!?

Comment: Yes you can create a new table using same name after droping your table

Comment: Excellent. By the way, @MKhalidJunaid would kindly provide this as an "answer", so that I am able to select it officially. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Grateful If you want to end up with same table, but no records, then just use `TRUNCATE TABLE`.  A truncate is a drop, followed by the `CREATE TABLE` command originally used for that table.

Comment: @Grateful you can accept Tim Biegeleisen's answer which elaborates morethan for what you have asked in your post

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid If you insist... But I generally prefer answers that stick to the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `DROP TABLE` will remove the entire table and all records contained inside it.  If you want to retain the table structure but remove all data, then consider using [`TRUNCATE TABLE`.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html)  Truncating a table is implemented by dropping the entire table and then recreating it.  This is faster than doing `DELETE FROM yourTable`, which removes records one-by-one.

Comment: Sy seems to have downvoted all the answers for some reason.

Comment: @Shadow Some people on this site have a serious downvote trigger finger problem.  I'm not one of them :-P

Answer (score 2):

After `Drop Table`, the table will not exist anymore, so no data and no table definition(which you called 'table shell'); `TRUNCATE TABLE` keep your table definition and delete all the data ,and reset table auto-increment as well, but be careful about `TRUNCATE` if the table size is huge, it will expand your tablespace and not easy to shrink.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the description. I will try and remember that.

Answer (score 0):

As mysql manual on [drop table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html) says:

> Be careful with this statement! It removes the table definition and all table data.

So, no shell (whatever that should mean) remains after dropping a table.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by table shell?

From MqSQL dev site:

> DROP TABLE removes one or more tables. You must have the DROP privilege for each table.

[Be careful with this statement! It removes the table definition and all table data. For a partitioned table, it permanently removes the table definition, all its partitions, and all data stored in those partitions. It also removes partition definitions associated with the dropped table.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html)